# Make won't work when trying to build on a different raspberry pi

Tags: c++, linux, bash, raspberry-pi, embedded-linux

I have a c++ based hardware driver code that talks to some circuitry to read data. It is running perfectly, on one Rasbperry Pi.

I transferred the complete code from this raspberry pi to another one. Now on this new raspberry pi, the 'make' command won't work.

The error says:
error while loading share libraries: libwiringPi.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It seems self-explanatory -- that library is missing on the other RPi.

Comment: Missing dependencies like that are easy to resolve if they're part of some kit you can install with `dnf` or `apt` or whatever package manager you're using.

Comment: A lot of projects have `configure` command you are supposed to run before `make` that does simple tests to verify all dependencies (and give instructions on installing missing dependencies).

Comment: `sudo apt-get install wiringpi` on the 2nd pi.

Comment: Thank you y'all. Everything you mentioned was super helpful. Turns out that there was a specific version of wiringpi released for RaspberryPi 4B, which is here. I installed this and dependency was handled. Problem Solved!! http://wiringpi.com/wiringpi-updated-to-2-52-for-the-raspberry-pi-4b/